# How to keep OnCompleteListener run after activity or app destroy?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

As per the [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)),

```
public Task<TResult> addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<TResult> lis
```

is not activity scoped listener.

what i have used

```
task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Task completed successfully
            AuthResult result = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Task failed with an exception
            Exception exception = task.getException();
        }
    }
});
```

i have noticed that ,
after start of `UploadTask` if I immediately exit from the app and also clear app from the recent, UploadTask is asynchronously complete, but `OnCompleteListener` is not work and also onComplete is not execute.

so how to keep run `addOnCompleteListener` after the activity or app destroy totally

Comment: you can use AsyncTask.

Comment: it is already asyncTask

Comment: Do it in a background service

Comment: it not possible in above o